# Placing elements on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a drag and drop function going on in HTML.

I also made a canvas.

I added the code of my HTML5 drag/drop unto the code where the canvas is. However the images dont appear on the canvas.

Could anyone tell me what I should replace so that it appears correctly on the canvas?

I've tried changing the ID's of the function placemap and placeback to match the id of the canvas, but that didn't work...

Thanks

```
<h2>Place your hero on the map</h2>


<canvas width=1200 height=350 id='map_id'>
</canvas>

<script>

// setup
var canvas = document.getElementById('map_id');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var hmap = Math.min(0.9 * screen.height, 0.45 * screen.width);
var numHeroes = 101;
var rows = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numHeroes))+5;
var hsize = Math.floor((1.0 / rows) * hmap);

function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    document.getElementById(data).style.left = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - 0.5 * parseInt(document.getElementById(data).style.height) + "px";
    document.getElementById(data).style.top = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - 0.5 * parseInt(document.getElementById(data).style.height) + "px";
}

function placeMap()
{
    var map = document.getElementById("map");
    map.style.left = "0px";
    map.style.top = "0px";
    map.style.height = hmap + "px";
    map.style.width = hmap + "px";
}

function placeBack()
{
    var map = document.getElementById("back");
    map.style.left = hmap + "px";
    map.style.top = "0px";
    map.style.height = hmap + "px";
    map.style.width = hmap + "px";
}

function place(id, num)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.left = hmap + hsize * (num % rows) + "px";
    img.style.top = hsize * Math.floor(num / rows) + "px";
    img.style.height = hsize + "px";
    img.style.width = hsize + "px";
}

function placeWard(id, num)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.left = hmap + (1+(num % 2)) * 0.5 * hsize + "px";
    img.style.top = 7.5 * hsize + Math.floor(num / 2) * 0.5 * hsize + "px";
    img.style.height = 0.5*hsize + "px";
    img.style.width = 0.5*hsize + "px";
}

</script>


<!-- draw a horizontal line -->

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using jQueryUI `draggable` instead of html `ondrag`?

If yes, here is example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/s4GUS/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var image1=new Image();
    image1.onload=function(){
    }
    image1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png";

    var $house=$("#house");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");

    $house.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
        // event handlers
        start:dragstart,
        drag:dragmove,
        stop:dragend,
    });
    // set the data payload
    $house.data("image",image1); // key-value pair

    $canvas.droppable({
        drop:dragDrop,
    });

    function dragstart(e){
```

//          console.log("dragstart");
        }

```
    function dragmove(e){
```

//          console.log("dragmove:"+e.clientX+"/"+e.clientY);
        }

```
    function dragend(e,ui){
      // relative to document
      var dragX=ui.offset.left;
      var dragY=ui.offset.top;
      // top-left of dropped element is at canvasXY
      var canvasX=dragX-offsetX;
      var canvasY=dragY-offsetY
    }

    function dragDrop(e,ui){
        var element=ui.draggable;
        var data=element.data("url");
        var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
        var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);
        ctx.drawImage(element.data("image"),x-1,y);            
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png"><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I'm trying to learn how to do it in html for now without using jQuery.